# can not update system

Tags: apt

Can anyone please help me with[image: this]
? should i login as root and kill the process?

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text.

Answer (score 1):

You need to close all applications using `apt`, or wait while unattended upgrades finish.

If you are using Ubuntu, you can't login as root.